# Why fillna does not work on float values?

Tags: python

I try to replace in all the empty cell of a dataset the mean of that column.

I use `modifiedData=data.fillna(data.mean())`

but it works only on integer column type.
I have also a column with float values and in it `fillna` does not work.

Why?

Comment: Please provide some example data with a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Works with my data, yours must be different.

Answer (score 2):

`.fillna()` works on columns that are `nan`. The concept of `nan` can't exist in an `int` column. Pandas dtype `int` does not support `nan`.
If you have a column with what seems to be integers, it is more likely an object column. Perhaps even filled with strings. Strings that are empty in some cases.

Empty strings are not filled by `.fillna()`

```
In [8]: pd.Series(["2", "1", ""]).fillna(0)
Out[8]: 
0    2
1    1
2     
dtype: object
```

An easy way to figure out what's going on is to use the `df.Column.isna()` method.

If that method gives you all `False`. you know there are no `nan` to fill.

To turn empty strings into `nan` values

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(["2", "1", ""])
In [12]: empty_string_mask = s.str.len() == 0
In [21]: s.loc[empty_string_mask] = float('nan')
In [22]: s
Out[22]: 
0      2
1      1
2    NaN
dtype: object
```

After that you can `fillna`

```
In [23]: s.fillna(0)
Out[23]: 
0    2
1    1
2    0
dtype: object
```

Another way of going about this problem is to check the dtype

```
df.column.dtype
```

If it says `'object'` It confirms your issue

You can cast the column to a float column

```
df.column = df.column.dtype(float)
```

Though manipulating dtypes in pandas usually leads to pains, this may be an easier route to take for this particular problem.